# to grate cheese with a saw not Toveled?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, maseches-shabbos, muktzeh, tevilas-keilim-dipping

The *mishna* in Masechet Shabbat says:

> A man may take a hammer to split nuts, a chopper to cut [a round of] pressed figs, a saw for sawing cheese, a spade to scoop dried figs, a winnowing shovel and a pitchfork to place [food] upon it for a child, a reed or a whorl to stick [food], a small needle to remove a thorn, and a sack [needle] to open a door therewith.

We are allowed to use tools on food which are not designed for food on Shabbat, like a saw to grate cheese [image: e.g. Parmigiano]

The topic of the *mishna* is ***Muktse***.

But an additional problem may be of ***Tevilat Kelim*** if the tools are manufactured by gentiles.

Do commentaries or poskim infer from this *mishna* that *tevila* is not necessary for incidental use? The saw will remain a saw to work with wood. Two defects:

- 1 time (as a new cup which you want to use 1 time before its tevila)
- not essential (the contact with food will be for one time only and there is no reason to make tevila after this unic use).

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/51158

Comment: @msh210 Your link is good. My question is if the Mishna I refered is used about the topic. It is not clear for me.

Comment: Accidental is probably not what you mean. Perhaps you mean occasional abnormal or uncommon? Accidental may mean abnormal in musical notation but in this situation it would mean having used it without thinking, and keilim which lack tevilah never make the foods inedible.

Comment: @user6591 yes, you are right, I mean not programmed. I mean that in some not programed situation, we need this Keli for food consummation

Comment: @user6591 I see that Waf replaced it by incidental. Nuances in English are not understandable for me. In hebrew. באקראי

Comment: `But an additional problem may be of Tevilat Kelim if the tools are manufactured by gentiles` The inference only stands in the Mishna s specifically talking about gentile-made kelim. Considering that there is no mention of this in the Mishna, why make such an _ukimta_, especially considering that there is no reason for the Mishna talking to be talking about this case, as it has nothing to do with the case at hand?

Comment: @mevaqesh I don't make any okimta in the mishna  ;-)  an okimta is to decide that the Mishna is restricted to some cases only.

Comment: @mevaqesh the question may be asked anyway no matter with the Mishna but I want to to ask it as I asked it.

Comment: when you buy a saw you take it to mikveh?  @mevaqesh

Comment: @mevaqesh perhaps knw you someone who can explain you the question?  I am sorry if it is too hard.